# Razor pages entire model object as a option value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I am looking for a way to pass currently selected model from view to controller.
My select code:

```
<select asp-for="Product">
            @foreach (var p in Model.Products)
            {
                <option value="@p">@p.ProductName</option>  
            }
        </select>
```

I'm trying to bind option value @p to bind with my property below:

```
[BindProperty]
    public Product Product { get; set;}
```

But whenever after submitting my form the Product property has "null" values. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a hidden type for this. No need to query to find ProductName after submit in list.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductName" />
    <select asp-for="ProductId">
                @foreach (var p in Model.Products)
                {
                    <option value="@p.Id">@p.ProductName</option>  
                }
            </select>

<script>
        $(function () {
            $('form').submit(function () {                
                var productName = $('#ProductId option:selected').text();
                $('#ProductName').val(productName);
             });
         });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think you misundrestood me. I have IEnumerable<Product> Products which im looping trough, to create an selection for user.
And when user selects one of those Products then i want to pass that selected Product object to the public Product Product property. Not just the Id of that. (I might be happy enough with the id tho, i can select the product from the IEnumerable products according to the received Id).

Comment: @KevinBasov: Yep, got it. But when you submit, List Product in the model will null, right? I think it will be easy if you get more ProductName property when submit. And then rebind Product property in the model using ProductId and ProductName.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would pass the Id of the selected item when the form is posted. That is typically enough data to work with. However, if you really want the ModelBinder to create a Product instance from the posted values, your form fields should be named `Product.ProductId` and `Product.ProductName`. The other answer shows how to obtain the ProductName value and then assign it to a hidden field.

```
<select asp-for-"Product.ProductId" asp-items="Model.Products">
...
</select>

<input type="hidden" asp-for="Product.ProductName" />
```